# Why is my rendering in cycles NOT grainy at all?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm following Blender Guru's doughnut tutorial and have the rendering engine to cycles. At first, the render was grainy, as it should be. I stepped away from the computer for a while to wait as it renders an image and when I came back, the screen was blank, probably from crashing.

I opened up blender again, and the doughnut wasn't grainy at all, like in Eevee rendering. I didn't save the project before it presumably crashed but I don't think I lost any actual progress. I know this isn't an actual problem, and I'm not gonna complaining about the smooth rendering but I'm a bit worried that some settings are off and that that might screw me over later. Rendering image still takes time though, and the image turns out a little grainy. Any idea why this is, or did my mac just randomly transcend into a super computer?

Comment: I found the problem. I got switched to material preview when the mac crashed and not render preview. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

what you mentioned does appear to be denoising , in the cycles render properties tab below the samples , check for the denoising properties , inside the denoising , you wil find 2 options , render and viewport denoising , render denoising is used for deoising your render , which means that the denoising will not appear in the render

Comment: Both denoise buttons are unchecked, so I don't think that's it. Checking the boxes doesnt' really seem to do much either.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem. I got switched to material preview when the mac crashed and not render preview. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't add thank you as an answer, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted